# Django Selenium liveserver doesn't get started when running tests

Tags: django, selenium

I am building a Django website and I am using Selenium to test my pages. My problem is that when I run the tests, the browser is launched, but no page is loaded or even attempted to be loaded. It just opens blank and the tests hang. It seems to me that the liveserver doesn't get started. I am running on Apache2 and WSGI, but my understanding is that the Selenium tests are run by the the Django's built-in web server. Any idea what could be wrong? The relevant files are below:

tests.py:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver

class MyProjectLiveServerTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def initSeleniumDriver(cls):
        cls.driver = WebDriver()

    @classmethod
    def closeSeleniumDriver(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()

    def testIndexShouldLoad(self):
        self.driver.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/nd5/mybook/'))
        self.assertEqual(len(self.driver.find_elements(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR,
            'span#copyright'
        )), 1)
```

settings.py:

```
# Test database runs on SQLite
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..', 'myprojectdb'),
    }
}

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
```

I am using django-nose, so I execute the tests this way:

```
python manage.py test --exe
```

Please, let me know if you need to see any other parts of the code.

**UPDATE:**

Here is update: I found out that the reason Firefox doesn't load the page is because my version of Firefox is newer than the latest version supported by Selenium. So I switched to Chrome and now the URL in the browser is requested. However, the page isn't found (404 error). This must mean that the liveserver is still not running. My tests don't turn on the liveserver when they get run. Any idea why? The port isn't blocked - I checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to select webdriver to use:

```
class SomethingTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(2)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_user_can_log_in(self):
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + reverse('something'))
        self.fail('write rest of the test')
```

Comment: This is not obvious from my code I posted above, but the WebDriver() call is a Firefox webdriver. It's imported like so `from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver`.

Comment: If the browser window starts without any URL, it could be that you are inserting invalid URL. That can be caused by self.live_server_url being None. I would start a debugger (pip install pudb and  import pudb; pudb.set_trace() on the line before attempting the GET request). So you will see, if the test method is really executed and what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

This probably wasn't your problem, but what bit me was that `LiveServerTestCase` starts the server thread from `setUpClass`, which I'd defined without calling `super(MyProjectLiveServerTestCase, self).setUpClass()`.